# Deriving the massless Dirac equation in static spherical sphere spacetime?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, dirac-equation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I am a physics postgraduate and was curious if what I've done below was the correct equation for neutrinos in curved space time?

### Deriving the massless dirac equation using differential geometry

Beginning with the line element:

$$ ds^2 = (c dt)^2 - dr^2$$

Taking the square root of the metric and using the gamma matrices:

$$ ds =  \gamma^0 c dt -  \gamma^i \cdot dr_i$$

For time like geodesics: $ ds = 0$. Taking the dual basis:

$$ 0 =  \frac{1}{c}\gamma^0 \partial _t - \gamma^i \cdot \nabla_i$$

To convice yourself of the above formula use $\langle dx^i | \partial_j \rangle = \delta^{i}_j $

Multiplying $i \hbar$ both sides and the wave function we obtain:

$$ 0=i\hbar \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi $$

### Using the same technique for static spherical symmetrical line element:

$$ds^2 = -(1-\frac{2M}{r}) dt^2 + (1-\frac{2M}{r})^{-1}  dr^2 $$

Taking square root and setting $ds = 0$ (as done above):

$$ 0 = \gamma^0 dt - \gamma^i \cdot (1-\frac{2M}{r})^{-1} dr $$

Again using the dual basis and multiplying $\psi$:

$$ 0 = \gamma^0 \partial_t \psi- \gamma^i \cdot (1-\frac{2M}{r}) \nabla \psi $$

Multiplying $i \hbar$ we have:

$$ i \gamma^0 \hat E \psi =  \gamma^i\cdot (1-\frac{2M}{r}) \nabla \psi$$

### Question

Is the final equation correct? How does one go from the infinitesimal equation to the dual basis equation in the massive (with mass) case? Where can I read more about these methods?

Comment: It is correct to see the Dirac operator as the inverse of the Riemann metric. This is routine in Alain Connes' noncommutative geometry.

Comment: @Jon is $ i \gamma^0 \hat E \psi =  \gamma^i \cdot  (1-\frac{2M}{r}) \nabla \psi$ is then correct? Where can I read more about this? (Which papers)

Comment: I should say that you are missing at least the $g_{00}$ term and so, you should fix the last equation. About noncommutative geometry, there is a lot of too much mathematical literature. To have an idea, check http://www.alainconnes.org/en/ where you can download a lot of material for free.

Comment: @Jon I think I've done a simplification:
$ ds = 0 = -(1-2M/r)^{1/2} \gamma^0 dt  - \gamma^i \cdot  (1-2M/r)^{-1/2} $ ... Now dividing $ (1-2M/r)^{1/2} $ on both sides we get the equation. If it is not correct feel free to correct?

Comment: There is a further problem with your formulation: Spin couples with gravity. You should also consider a covariant derivative. E.g. see http://www.m-hikari.com/astp/astp2007/astp5-8-2007/zeccaASTP5-8-2007.pdf.